# Google Map's callout view

Tags: java, android, google-maps, mapbox, callout

For my Android App I'm using MapBox. Tapping a marker shows a calloutview in the shape of a balloon like expected. Google maps uses a different type of callout view. A view appears on the bottom and when tapped, the view scrolls over the map showing more information about the marker. Is there a specific name for this view? Or maybe a library which does the same thing? Or is it completely custom?

If so is this accomplished by adding a new fragment on top of the MapView? Any help would be much appreciated.

Added some screenshots to clarify what I mean.

*Please don't mind the volume bar as it's ridiculously hard to take a screenshots without my device registering a single volume down push -_-*

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a view affiliated with the map, so it wouldn't be similar to a Tooltip or callout - you would listen for a touch event on a marker, and then rearrange the view *surrounding* the `MapView`, transitioning a separate detail view up and transitioning the map to a different centerpoint.

Comment: Right. So is it a good way to place a fragment on top of the mapview and let that view listen to touches so it can show and hide?